# Trying to find the number of instances of Column B in Column A and output a result in a subquery

Tags: sql, db2

So, I'm trying to do the following: If Store has 1 fruit, then output 'SINGLE'. If it has more than 1 fruit, then output 'MULTIPLE'. I have tried this in a separate SQL file with just querying the table:

```
SELECT STORE, FRUIT
CASE
WHEN COUNT(FRUIT) > 1
THEN 'MULTIPLE'
ELSE 'SINGLE'
AS NO_FRUIT
FROM STORES
GROUP BY STORE, FRUIT;
```

This seems to give the output that I want, which is something like:

```
STORE      |FRUIT |NO_FRUIT
---------------------------
SUPERMARKET|TOMATO|MULTIPLE
---------------------------
WETMARKET  |APPLE |SINGLE
```

I'm trying to do this inside a select query itself which is selecting many other fields from many other tables that I need, which I think would make this into a subquery. I'm not quite sure how to make it work. Any help is appreciated!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Actually your logic suggests that you want to aggregate by store alone, and then check the count of fruits:

```sql
SELECT STORE,
       CASE WHEN COUNT(*) > 1 THEN 'MULTIPLE' ELSE 'SINGLE' END AS NO_FRUIT
FROM STORES
GROUP BY STORE;
```

**Edit:** If you want to retain all columns, then you instead can use `COUNT` as an analytic function.

```sql
SELECT STORE, FRUIT,
       CASE WHEN COUNT(*) OVER (PARTITION BY STORE) > 1
            THEN 'MULTIPLE' ELSE 'SINGLE' END AS NO_FRUIT
FROM cte
ORDER BY STORE;
```

Comment: A couple of issues I'm having: 

1)I would still need all the rows to be shown, so I shouldn't be using GROUP BY.

2) Is there a way to make this into a subquery to be already used into a existing select statement?

Comment: @Azaqi Then use `COUNT` as an analytic function instead.

Comment: Looks like it works! Waiting for confirmation from my senior that it's correct. Once I get that, will accept your answer :)